# Ultimate waterfall chart on power bi

Tags: charts, powerbi, waterfall

im creating a waterfall chart with 3 measures as seen in the picture attached. However need a small tweak in the chart.

Column third (from left) has measure named "Notice2ContactwithLA" to it which shows value +29, I would like this column to start from 0.00 , just like how "Notice2voidstart" column looks like  [Ultimate waterfall picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMiWi.png)